# Legacy SQL - How does this query compile?

Tags: google-bigquery

I came across a surprising behaviour in Legacy SQL. Indeed, I launched this query by accident (I replace the `'[[date]]'` programmatically, I just forgot to replace it in UI) :

```
SELECT DATE(ComputationDate) as date 
FROM [project:dataset.table]
WHERE DATE(ComputationDate) < '[[date]]' 
ORDER BY date
```

And it worked ! I retrieved all data to today date. This fails in Standard SQL but was it an intended behaviour ?

It is not that much an issue but if my replacement fails, I cannot see it from code since the query still compiles.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Below version (BigQuery Legacy SQL) will return no rows at all which can be good indicator for you that something went wrong

```
#legacySQL
SELECT DATE(ComputationDate) as date 
FROM [project:dataset.table]
WHERE DATE(ComputationDate) < DATE('[[date]]') 
ORDER BY date
```

Answer (score 0):

The "culprit" is how it is cast under the hood. In my test, your query will return all the data for any string that cannot be parsed to a date type.